# python parser.parse_args() cutting off string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, argparse, amazon-emr

I am passing a string from EMR to a python file's main function into argparse. The string I'm passing looks like:

```
--my_arg "{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"}}"
```

The add_argument in the python file's main looks like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test file', add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('--my_arg', type=str, help='my helpful comment')
my_arg = args.my_arg
```

After this, I print out my_arg in the python file. That print statement looks like:

```
"{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"
```

Why is it cutting off the last two brackets?? I can't convert it into a python dictionary, unless I update the string with the missing '}}' after it's been parsed, which I'd prefer not to do.

The print out of sys.argv is:

```
'{"level_one_key": {"level_two_key": "level_two_value"'
```

When I pass this arg:

```
--my_arg "{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"} }"
```

The print out looks like:

```
"{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"} }
```

Comment: This feels like some issue with escaping characters and the handoff between EMR and Python.  Can you just `print(sys.argv)` to see what the arguments look like there.  I would wager that at that point, you're already missing the trailing brackets.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce your problem. I can print out the full value of `my_arg`.

Comment: @KyleParsons - yes, I think does have to do with escaping characters, but I am not sure how exactly. I added the print out of sys.argv

Comment: What happens if you pass the different, but equivalent (assuming JSON), string `"{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"} }"` (with a space between the two trailing `}`s)?

Comment: @chepner - that definitely helps. It's printing out both brackets now, but no quote at the end. I updated the original post with the print out

Comment: How exactly are you running the code? (I didn't really have any idea what to expect from the change; my suggestion was based on the fact that `{{ ... }}` is a way to delimit Python expressions in Jinja.)  I was assuming you were using a shell command like `python myscript --my_arg --my_arg "{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"} }"`, but I can't explain how your opening quote would be preserved as part of the value in that case.

Comment: I am using a local python file to generate the step on an existing aws emr cluster. my_arg is passed to emr via add_job_flow_steps as args in HadoopJarStep.